# Append query in VBA for microsoft access not taking the WHERE parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access, append

I have this function:

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strInsert As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strInsert = "INSERT INTO items_affected_Table(CR_Id, VerOld, Equipment_Serial, Document_No, Description, Version) SELECT Items_affected_Table.CR_Id, Items_affected_Table.Version, Items_affected_Table.Equipment_Serial, Items_affected_Table.Document_No, Items_affected_Table.Description, Items_affected_Table.VerNext FROM Items_affected_Table WHERE (((Items_affected_Table.CR_Id)=[Forms]![CR form-unapproved]![CR_ID]) AND ((Items_affected_Table.Version)=[Forms]![CR form-unapproved]![Version]))"

db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

It gives the error "too few parameters. Expected 2"

If I change the form references to actual numbers the append query works:

```
    strInsert = "INSERT INTO items_affected_Table(CR_Id, VerOld, Equipment_Serial, Document_No, Description, Version) SELECT Items_affected_Table.CR_Id, Items_affected_Table.Version, Items_affected_Table.Equipment_Serial, Items_affected_Table.Document_No, Items_affected_Table.Description, Items_affected_Table.VerNext FROM Items_affected_Table WHERE (((Items_affected_Table.CR_Id)=8) AND ((Items_affected_Table.Version)=0))"
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you duplicating records? Is CR_Id a primary key field?

Comment: Description is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names for anything. This can cause unexpected behavior. So is DESC so don't use that one either. Version is also listed as reserved http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate variable references:

```
strInsert = "INSERT INTO items_affected_Table(CR_Id, VerOld, Equipment_Serial, Document_No, Description, Version) " & _
             "SELECT CR_Id, Version, Equipment_Serial, Document_No, Description, VerNext " & _
             "FROM Items_affected_Table " & _
             "WHERE CR_Id=" & [Forms]![CR form-unapproved]![CR_ID] & " AND Version=" & [Forms]![CR form-unapproved]![Version]
```